# how to show msg box if user forgot to check asp.net checkbox control on button click ..?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

i have 20 checkboxes in usercontrol ... i wanna do whole coding in user control ...

how to show msg box  if user forgot to check asp.net checkbox control  on button click .. ?

Comment: Reference from your previous post: if user haven't checked any check box then on button click you will get vCheckedCBCount  = 0;then in JavaScript u can show alert message easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for every Checkbox which validates on client- and serverside if the Checkbox is checked.
http://www.joe-stevens.com/2009/08/12/using-the-customvalidators-clientvalidationfunction/

Comment: No i have 25 checkboxes in usercontrol and button1 i want if user forgot to check any of the checkboxes ( means user have to select atleast 1 checkbox to proceed on button click)

Comment: Do you have these checkboxes in any container like panel or table?

Comment: ya i have checkboxes in div and then table

Answer (score 0):

Create a public method on the user control that returns a boolean indicating if the data entry in the control is correct.  Call that method from your page on the button click event.  If data entry is valid, continue processing;else show an error message.

Comment: Can u have a coding example for this ?

Comment: I will post one shortly for you